# What do you do when you see an outdated question or answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

ServerFault and a lot of other SE sites have been around for a decade or more, but technologies advance very rapidly.

I recently came across [a ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/42973/how-to-use-symantec-backup-exec-with-s3-amazon-storage) with an answer which, although it might have addressed the question when it was posted 11 years ago, doesn't do that anymore.   Since the answer reinforces the now-incorrect premise of the question, it's also become misleading.

Right now, the only thing I'm confident will make any difference is to add a comment to this effect below the answer.

But: Is it reasonable to flag an answer or question for being badly outdated?  Are there any meaningful actions a moderator can take when they see such a flag?

I wonder if a custom "this is outdated" close reason would make sense (so I'm adding the feature-request tag).

Answer (score 5):

In such case I would suggest to post another answer AND to edit the actual accepted answer to write a notice at the answer bottom in a quoting style, something like that;

> Please know this answer was correct in the past. Now the support
>   [changed](https://www.serverfault.com).

For the ***changed*** word I would add a hyperlink to your actual answer.

The why I suggest that is that for historical's reason, it's good to know that in the past the product wasnt supported. In case you fall into an running instance and you ask yourselft, why the IT did that ?

So, for historical reason it's good to keep the actual answer there, but to edit and add an answer that is up to date it's perfectly ok.